# How to expose a C++ Model to QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm writing a QML+Qt application . 
I defined a class like this :

```
class MainClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    rosterItemModel m_rosterItemModel;
.
.
.
}
```

rosterItemModel model is a class derived from QAbstractListModel.
I exposed MainClass to qml part using this function :

```
qmlRegisterType<MainClass>("CPPIntegrate", 1, 0, "MainClass");
```

Now I want to assign this model(m_rosterItemModel) from MainClass to model property of a ListView in QML.
I tried the following ways but none of them were helpful :(

- I tried to declare m_rosterItemModel as a PROPERTY using Q_PROPERTY .
  I couldn't do that because it said that QAbstractListModel is not
  copy-able.
- I tried to get a pointer to m_rosterItemModel in qml file    using a
  Q_INVOKABLE function in MainClass. But it wasn't helpful too.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There shouldn't be any metatype registration necessary.
All you need to is to call setContextProperty and pass the model by *pointer*:

```
QQmlContext* context = view->rootContext(); //view is the QDeclarativeView
context->setContextProperty( "_rosterItemModel", &mainClassInstance->m_rosterItemModel );
```

Use it in QML:

```
model: _rosterItemModel
```

By pointer is important, as QObject's are not copy-constructible and copying them would break their semantics anyway (as they have an "identity").

The alternative to registering the model directly is to register your main class' instance and using Q_INVOKABLE. In MainClass:

```
Q_INVOKABLE RosterItemModel* rosterItemModel() const;
```

Registering an instance of mainClass (mainClassInstance again is assumed to be a pointer):

```
context->setContextProperty( "_mainInstance", mainClassInstance );
```

In QML:

```
model: _mainInstance.rosterItemModel()
```

Comment: I registered MainClass to QML using qmlRegisterType in order to use MainClass signals and slots easily in QML by creating an instance of it like MainClass{id:mc} . Anyway . thank u :)

Comment: It seems, from experience, that in the second case registering the model class in necassary too: `qmlRegisterType<rosterItemModel>("CPPIntegrate", 1, 0, "MainClass");` Also, using `const` modifier seems to break the interoperation. The last quirky bit is to always refer to the class with its full namespace qualification within the header's Q_PROPERTY and Q_INVOKABLE declarations. Besides, if one attemts to return some base class (like QAbstractItemModel) pointer, the interoperability will fail again, so beware.

Comment: How to get mainClassInstance?

Comment: Expose property from C++ to QML is ok, but why "get a pointer to m_rosterItemModel in qml file using a Q_INVOKABLE function in MainClass" fail?

Comment: Since mainClassInstance is also a QObject why aren't you also passing it by pointer in your second example?

Comment: @OpenLearner: The snippets assume that `mainClassInstance` is a `MainClass*`, so it's passed by pointer.