# Is there any way to use a C++ class as a QML component which would be available in designer to drag & use?

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I have a C++ class in which I set the image path which will be available only at run time. I want to use my class as a Custom QML component which should be available in designer tab & I can drag that & use in form editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate logic from view.
For an starting point, expose your images paths as model into QML and use a `ListView` with a `Rectangle` as delegate and assign model to it. Therefore you have a rectangle for each image path.
For more information read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806324/how-to-expose-a-c-model-to-qml)

***Please note** that registering QML Component in Qt 5.15+ has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I am facing issue to see my cpp component in designer, because it is registered in main.cpp while running of the application. But Designer cant see it at designing time. How can I make my Cpp custom component so it will be available in designer?